# Vue ошибка Avoid mutating a prop directly

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Учу Vuejs. По событию клика на кнопке в дочернем компоненте вызываю метод, который передает событие в родительский компонент, затем в родителе инлайн меняется значение переменной. Вью на такое дело ругается.

**Ошибка:**

```
[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "carName"
```

**Вот компонент родителя:**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <app-car :carName="carName" :carYear="carYear" @nameChanged="this.carName = $event"></app-car>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "app",
  data() {
    return {
      carName: 'Ford',
      carYear: 2018
    }
  }
}; 
</script>
```

**Дочерний компонент:**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h3>{{ carName }}</h3>
        <p>{{ carYear }}</p>
        <button @click="changeName">Change Name</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['carName', 'carYear'],
        methods: {
            changeName() {
                this.carName = 'Mazda'
                this.$emit('nameChanged', this.carName)
            }
        }    
    }
</script>
```

Подскажите как в этом случае лучше поступить, чтобы ошибки не было?

Comment: @nameChanged="this.carName = $event" из за этого

Comment: Это я понимаю. Подскажите как поменять свойство правильно. Я понимаю что эта строчка хоть и приводит к ожидаемому результату, но является костылем с точки зрения вью, на что она и ругается.